# rm -I to prevent accidental rm

Tags: rm, coreutils

I just created `alias rm="rm -I"` to prevent from accidental `rm` command.

```
-I     prompt  once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.
       Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

But it doesn't work. I don't get any prompt when I use `rm -rf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the help *again* you'll see it says ***previous*** `--interactive`. This means you can add an `-I` after all the other arguments (like at the end of the line) and it'll be honoured again!

To do that, you need a function instead of an alias, but just stick this somewhere in your `.bashrc` (et al)  and you're golden:

```
function rm { /bin/rm "$@" -I; }
```

---

A perhaps safer method than even this is using `trash-cli`'s `trash-put` command. It will put things in your account's trash directory that can be reviewed/restored/emptied normally. It also has dummy `-r`, `-f` and, `-i` arguments so it makes a perfect alias possible:

```
alias rm="trash-put"
```

Comment: Sounds fair, but better is not playing with `-rf` ;)

Comment: as long as one of those arguments isn't `--`...

Comment: @DrakeClarris Yeah I've been thinking about that. This is a bash function so we could pick apart the "$@", searching for ` --` and replacing it with `-I --`. You'd also need to make sure that was unquoted. It feels like this would be pretty tedious to work around.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that `-f` makes `rm` ignore any interactive command:

```
`-f'
`--force'
   Ignore nonexistent files and missing operands, and never prompt
   the user.  Ignore any previous `--interactive' (`-i') option.
```

Source: `info coreutils 'rm invocation'`

Comment: So what option do I have to save myself from `rm -rf`?

Comment: @Sourabh just don't type it...

Comment: This has been beaten to death on other threads, but it's still worth mentioning. It's not a good idea to create aliases or scripts that modify the behavior of common commands. 1) If you get used to the new behaviour and then use another system, it will not work as you expect. 2) If anyone else ever uses your system (e.g. to help you solve a problem), then those commands will not work as they expect them to. It's fine to have aliases and custom scripts, that's what Linux is about. Just don't name them the same as preexisting commands.